# sequence characterization of first countable space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ equipped with two different first countable topology $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ ,assume $x_n\to x$ in $\tau_1$ iff $x_n\to x$ in $\tau_2$,prove $\tau_1 = \tau_2$.

My attempt:$x\in \bar{A} \iff \text{exist}\ x_n\to x$ then we know any closure $\text{cl}_1 A = \text{cl}_2 A$ for any set $A$.

But I don't know to show then topology are the same?

Comment: Can you show that $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ have the same closed sets?

Comment: Thanks I have worked it out,it's a very simple question.I was outside few minutes ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a closed set in $X$ with respect to $\tau_1$ and $x \in \bar{A}=A$ , then there exists ${x_n\to x}$ in $A$ in $\tau_1$ ,but as  ${x_n\to x}$ in $\tau_2$ which is in $A$, it implies $x \in \bar{A}$ with respect to $\tau_2$. Therefore Closure of $A$ in $\tau_1$
equals to Closure of $A$ in $\tau_2$.
$\therefore$ cl$_2A$=cl$_1A$=$A$. Therefore $A$ is closed in $\tau_2$. Likewise we can prove that, if $B$ be a closed set in $\tau_2$ then it is closed in $\tau_1$. Which implies $\tau_1$=$\tau_2$